# Can I reuse Mono in case of unexpected error

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have the following code

```
    Mono<FileInfo> fileInfoMono = getFileInfo(fileName, filelocation);

    return fileInfoMono.map(info -> fileReader.read(info)
        .doOnNext(this::log)
        .flatMap(info -> processFile(info))
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> handleAndReturnEmpty(throwable, fileInfoMono));
  }
```

```
private Mono<FileInfo> handleAndReturnEmpty(Throwable cause, Mono<FileInfo> fileInfoMono {
    return fileInfoMono.doOnNext(info -> logError(cause.getMessage())
        .flatMap(errorService::handleUnexpectedError)
        .flatMap(info -> Mono.empty());
  }
```

The idea of this code is that I get a file information and then do some file processing. If any unexpected exception occurs, I need to handle it (move to `error` folder, for example). For this, I need to get the current file location (this is what `FileInfo` for).

Are there any ways to reuse the same Mono? Because currently it doesn't work and doesn't get me any messages

Comment: I guess you can use some `cache` with a shared copy of it. But in you case it seems too excessive to do so just for error handling. Maybe you could handle the error as a part of the processing like `processFile(info).onErrorResume(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is to move the further logic to a separate method using `flatMap`.

In such case `fileInfo` will be available as a normal object in the method params. Or just reactive execution inside `flatMap` statement, that is totally the same

```
getFileInfo(fileName, filelocation).flatMap(fileInfo -> fileReader.read(fileInfo)
        .doOnNext(this::log)
        .flatMap(info -> processFile(info))
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> handleAndReturnEmpty(throwable, fileInfo));
```